# Unable to set environment variables using Chef tomcat

Tags: chef-infra, tomcat8, cookbook

I am using a cookbook from https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/tomcat

```
instance_name = node['tomcat']['name']

# Install the Tomcat Service
tomcat_install instance_name do
  version node['tomcat']['version']
  dir_mode '0755'
  install_path node['tomcat']['install_dir']
  tarball_uri node['tomcat']['install_tar']
  tomcat_user node['tomcat']['user']
  tomcat_group node['tomcat']['group']
end

tomcat_service instance_name do
  action [:start, :enable]
  env_vars [{ 'CATALINA_PID' => '/opt/tomcat_helloworld/bin/non_standard_location.pid' }, { 'SOMETHING' => 'some_value' }]
  sensitive true
end
```

I am expected to find an env variable named SOMETHING, but when I do

```
echo $SOMETHING
```

I don't find any, also I don't find the setenv.sh in #{derived_install_path}/bin/setenv.sh
with this variable as well, but this file does not exist.

Comment: The behaviour of `tomcat_service` may differ based on Linux distributions. Which distro are you using?

Comment: I am using Centos 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `env_vars` property of `tomcat_service` custom resource sets the environment variables for the Tomcat service `instance_name`. *These are not SHELL environment variables.*

> tomcat_service sets up the installed tomcat instance to run using the appropriate init system (sys-v, upstart, or systemd)

In CentOS services are handled by `systemctl` and hence these variables are added in the respective Systemd service file.

Example:

```
/etc/systemd/system/tomcat_helloworld.service
```

Snipped contents:

```
Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat_helloworld"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat_helloworld/bin/non_standard_location.pid"
Environment="SOMETHING=some_value"
```